# How do I import the substring into my Python code from Ubidots?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am new to programming and cloud computing. I am trying to control an `LED` using `Ubidots` and `Raspberry Pi`.

I have created a URL in `Ubidots` that controls the `LED` with values 0 and 1.

I need to put this `URL` (string) into my `Python` code, i.e., I need to retrieve the substring.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, some code. How can we help you if we don' t know what you've done. read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use Requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

They have a [tutorial for Raspberry Pi](http://ubidots.com/docs/devices/raspberrypi.html#raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet), it's pretty straightforward. It's explained using their Python library, so everything you are asking is actually covered on it.

This is what you can use to [send a value using their Python library](http://ubidots.com/docs/devices/raspberrypi.html#send-one-value-to-ubidots) and print the response from the server:

```
from ubidots import ApiClient
import math
import time

# Create an ApiClient object

api = ApiClient(token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

# Get a Ubidots Variable

variable = api.get_variable('YOUR_VARIABLE_ID')

response = variable.save_value({"value": 1})
print response
```

Or also, this is what you can use to [get a value using their Python library](http://ubidots.com/docs/devices/raspberrypi.html#get-one-value-from-ubidots) and print the response from the server:

```
from ubidots import ApiClient
import random

#Create an "API" object

api = ApiClient(token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

#Create a "Variable" object

variable = api.get_variable("YOUR_VARIABLE_ID")

#Get the value from Ubidots
last_value = variable.get_values(1)
print last_value
```

Answer (score 0):

After all these changes and updates on both (Raspberry Pi and Ubidots), I'd like to provide you with an easy and quick way to implement this idea.

**My setup**

*Hardware:*

Raspberry Pi 4 - Model B, connected to a LED

*Software:*

`gpiozero` Python library, [Ubidots Platform](https://ubidots.com/stem/) *(In Sep. 2021 the version was 1.6 in STEM plan.)*

---

1- Create a device on Ubidots, with Switch widget (on/off) in a new dashboard.

2- Import the required libraries (in my case:)

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
import requests
```

3- Copy your account token from Ubidots and the device details as below:

```
TOKEN = "#############################"  # Put your TOKEN here
DEVICE = "led"  # Put your device label here 
VARIABLE = "led"  # Put your first variable label here
```

4- Create an object for LED (GPIO 17 in my case):

```
led = LED(17)  # GPIO17
```

5- Build a function that will receive the response from the Ubidots API.

```
def get_led_status(device, variable):
    try:
        url = f"http://industrial.api.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/devices/{device}/{variable}/"
        headers = {"X-Auth-Token": TOKEN, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        req = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        return req.json()['last_value']['value']
    except:
        pass
```

6- Reflect the response on your hardware as below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        led_status = get_led_status(DEVICE, VARIABLE)
        print(led_status)
        if led_status == 0:
            led.off()
        elif led_status == 1:
            led.on()
        sleep(1)
```

For more details about connecting your RPi with Ubidots, follow this article from [here](https://help.ubidots.com/en/articles/513309-connect-the-raspberry-pi-with-ubidots).

I hope this helps in 2021.